# Is there an efficient implementation of a FIFO queue and/or linked list built into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, queue, fifo

I'm writing algorithms that utilize a (FIFO) queue for efficiency. Namely, a list structure where you can append to the end of the list in O(1) time, and also remove from the front of the list in O(1) time.

Arrays can append to the end and remove from the front, but only appending to the end (with the `append()` method) is O(1) (amortized) time. Removing from the front (with the `shift()` method) is O(n) time.

Linked lists can do both appending to the end and removing from the front in O(1) time, so if there's a good linked list implementation built into Javascript, then I could use that for efficient queues.

I've Googled around and haven't been able to find either of these things - do they exist?

Comment: i dont think you'll find built in implementations like in java. you can probably write your own or search on npm

Comment: It will be hard to find a more efficient implementation than the `unshift`/`pop` or `shift/push` combos. They are surprisingly fast, even though the (un)shift operations are supposed to have O(n) complexity, engines apply optimisations under the hood. If you have a practical problem where the performance of (un)shift is a problem, I'd like to see it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm mostly asking in the context of using Javascript for interviews. In interviews it matters what your runtime/space complexity is, even if there's not a practical use case where it would matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [built-in data structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) with O(1) append and remove from front operations in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a Set. As far as I can tell this is O(1).

```
const q = new Set();

q.add(2) //enqueue
q.add("HI")
q.add({a:1, b:0})
console.log(q.entries()) //print
const [head] = q;
console.log(head) //peek
q.delete(head) //dequeue is peek then delete
q.add(8)
console.log(q.entries()) //print
console.log(q.size); //length
q.clear() //clear
console.log(q.size === 0); //isEmpty
//...plus many other functions
```

Comment: A (FIFO) queue can have duplicates... So `q.add(1); q.add(1); ... q.delete(head);` should not result in an empty queue.

Comment: You are correct indeed, then we can go to built-in Map()